# Swift: Parsing JSON string without key

Tags: ios, json, swift

I would like to parse json string as following, I am wondring how to print [times] values

Json String:

```
{
date: "2014-08-13",
method: "Makkah: Umm al-Qura University, Makkah",
latitude: "30.0599153",
longtude: "31.2620199",
timezone: "+3",
times: [
"04:52",
"06:21",
"13:00",
"16:36",
"19:38",
"19:38",
"21:08"
] }
```

This is my code:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                let todayDate = json["date"]
                let method = json["method"]
                let latitude = json["latitude"]
                let longtude = json["longtude"]
                let timezone = json["timezone"]
```

so the question is, How to print the times, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let times = json["times"] as! [String]

for time in times {
   print(time) 
}
```

or in one line

```
times.forEach{ print($0) }
```

Comment: To clarify, times is an array. The JSON you posted is a dictionary containing a variety of key/value pairs. One of those is the key `times`, and the value for that key is an array of time strings.